# Insert a string into html code

Tags: html, css, powershell

So I am trying to insert and add strings into html code. What I am doing is reading in some strings from a text like so:

```
$getTxt = Get-Content -path test.txt

 $getJson.GetType() | Format-Table -AutoSize

foreach ($name in $getJson)
{
    $name
}
```

and then take the strings and insert them into this html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Stringer</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://stylesheet.link">


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>

<body>

<div class="ticker-wrap">
<div class="ticker">    
<div class="ticker__item">  <img src="image0.jpg" alt="" width="50" height="60"> "<insert text here>"</div>
 </div>


 </div>
 </div>


 </body>
 </html>
```

How can I insert text with the powershell script to create another iteration of

```
<div class="ticker__item">  <img src="image#.jpg" alt="" width="50" height="60"> "<insert text here>"</div>
```

for each string in the text file? (Assume their is a image file for each item in the string)

Comment: is this just appending to the file or does it need to go in a specific place in the file?

Comment: My assumption is that `<div class="ticker_item">` are to be inserted as children of `<div class="ticker">`. Appending to the file would put them outside the `</html>` tag.

Comment: Correct they are to be added as children into the body

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out in order to insert the code I basically took the original html and the json in test.txt. The Powershell will look like this:

```
$fileName = ""
$getHtml = Get-content -path index.html 
$getJson = Get-Content -path test.txt
$getJson.GetType() | Format-Table -AutoSize
$name = '<div class="ticker">'
$newhtml= ""
[int]$i = 0

foreach ($line in $getHtml)
{    

   $newHtml += $line + "`n"
   write-host "$newhtml"



   if($line -match $name) # if done like this we have to read the text file backwards unless we dump the entire loop before foing to the nextline
    {   
        $s = $line -match $name
        $newHtml += $name +"`n"    
        while($i -lt $getJson.Length)
        {             
    $line =  "  <div class=" + '"ticker__item"' + ">" + "<img src=" + '"image' + $i + '.jpg" ' + "alt=" + '"" ' + "width=" + '"50"' +  " height=" + '"60"' + ">" + $getJson[$i] + "</div>" + "`n"
    $i += 1
    $newHtml += $line
    write-host "$newhtml" 
        }        
}


}
```